# Removing the minimum value in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search-tree

I tried to print out my binary search tree in sorted order by using the `removeMin()` method, but somehow the output is not correct.

Here is my code:

```
public Node removeMin(Node insertNode){

  Node parentNode =root;
  if (insertNode.left != null){
    return removeMin(insertNode.left);
  }
  if (insertNode.right ==null){
    parentNode.left = null;
  }else {
    parentNode.left = removeMin(insertNode.right);
  }
  return insertNode;
}
```

Comment: What is the output? What is the expected output?

Comment: For starters, if you're not printing anything, I don't see how you can expect the output to be correct.

Comment: Where does `root` come from in `Node parentNode =root;` Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

check for node == NULL

```
public Node removeMin(Node root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (root.left != NULL){
        return removeMin(root.left);
    }
    if (insertNode.right == NULL){
        Node temp = root;
        root = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    else {
       return removeMin(root.right);
    }

  }
```

not checked..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private Node removeMin(Node node){
    if(node.left.left == null) {
        Node minNode = node.left;
        node.left = node.left.right;
        minNode.right = null;
        return minNode;
    } else {
        return removeMin(node.left);
    }
}

public Node removeMin() {
    if(root == null) {
        return null;
    } else if(root.left != null) {
        return removeMin(root);
    } else {
        Node minNode = root;
        root = root.right;
        minNode.right = null;
        return minNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: The important thing here is that removeMin can not remove the node that was passed as an argument because it doesn't have access to it's parent. That's why I wrote the code such that removeMin is never called with a node that has no left child. So I needed a second removeMin method to check whether the root has a left child. Also I assumed that all the children of the returned node should be null. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.